# Vue js & laravel in back end editing invoice

Tags: arrays, laravel, vuejs3

EDITED :

i am fetching these array from invoice_items with products matched invoice id

```
[
    {
        "id": 27,
        "invoice_id": 14,
        "product_id": 1,
        "unit_price": 200,
        "product_quantity": 4,
        "unit_id": 7,
        "tax_rate": 0,
        "tax_type": "exclusive",
        "discount_type": "flat",
        "discount": 0,
        "created_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:34.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:34.000000Z",
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "02381402314",
            "name": "Travel Beg",
            "slug": "man-travel-beg-black-and-white",
            "product_type": "simple",
            "barcode_symbology": "CODE128",
            "stock_quantity": 6,
            "stock_alert_quantity": null,
            "purchase_price": 100,
            "sale_price": 200,
            "parent_id": null,
            "brand_id": 2,
            "category_id": 1,
            "unit_id": 7,
            "purchase_unit_id": 7,
            "sale_unit_id": 7,
            "tax_id": null,
            "tax_type": "exclusive",
            "description": null,
            "created_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:33.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:33.000000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "invoice_id": 14,
        "product_id": 3,
        "unit_price": 12000,
        "product_quantity": 1,
        "unit_id": 8,
        "tax_rate": 15,
        "tax_type": "inclusive",
        "discount_type": "flat",
        "discount": 0,
        "created_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:34.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:34.000000Z",
        "product": {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "99080532114",
            "name": "Smart Phone Samsung A11 Black",
            "slug": "smart-phone-samsung-a11",
            "product_type": "single",
            "barcode_symbology": "CODE128",
            "stock_quantity": 4,
            "stock_alert_quantity": 13,
            "purchase_price": 10000,
            "sale_price": 12000,
            "parent_id": null,
            "brand_id": 9,
            "category_id": 13,
            "unit_id": 8,
            "purchase_unit_id": 8,
            "sale_unit_id": 8,
            "tax_id": 4,
            "tax_type": "inclusive",
            "description": "Latest Samsung Smart Phone.",
            "created_at": "2024-01-01T12:23:33.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-01-06T15:09:00.000000Z"
        }
    }
]
```

with the function fetchInvoiceProducts

```
  // Fetch invoice products
  const fetchInvoiceProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/products_invoice/14`);
      selected_items.value = response.data;
      console.log(selected_items)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching invoice products:', error);
    }
  };
```

then i am looping those array in my table as product to edit in my invoice as bellow

```
<table
      class="table bg-white table-bordered my-3 p-1 table-responsive"
  >
      <thead>
          <tr class="bg-ass text-secondary">
              <th class="min150">Product</th>
              <th class="min100">Unit Price</th>
              <th class="">Stock</th>
              <th class="min100">Quantity</th>
              <th class="min100">Tax</th>
              <th class="min100">Subtotal</th>
              <th class="min100">action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead> 
      {{ selected_items }} 
      <tbody v-if="selected_items.length > 0">
          <tr v-for="p in selected_items">
              <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.unit_price }}</td>
              <td>
                  <input
                      type="number"
                      class="max100 form-control"
                      :value="p.product_quantity"
                      disabled
                  />
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input
                      type="number"
                      class="max100 form-control"
                      min="1"
                      v-model="p.stock_quantity"
                      @input="calculateGrandTotal()"
                  />
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{
                      (
                                p.product_quantity *
                                ((((100 - p.tax_rate) *
                                    p.sale_price) /
                                    100) *
                                    (p.tax_rate / 100))
                            ).toFixed(2)
                  }}
                  $
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{
                      p.tax_type == "exclusive"
                          ? p.product_quantity *
                            (p.sale_price * (p.tax_rate / 100) +
                                p.sale_price)
                          : p.product_quantity * p.product.sale_price
                  }}
              </td>
              <td>
                  <CrossSvgIcon
                      @click="removeSelected(p.id)"
                      color="red"
                  />...
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

then result of the code above,

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Product      | Unit Price   | Stock | Quantity  | Tax    | Subtotal
-----------------------------------------------------------------
99080532114  | 200        | 6     | 2         | ...  | ...
02381402314  | 100        | 6     | 2         | ...  | ...
```

second party it's whe a client search for product to add from PRODUCT with a NAME and WARHOUSE ID

array from search product from PRODUCT
2 params : warehouse = ${selected_warehouse.value} AND  name = ${name}

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Casual Shoe for Man",
        "sale_price": 1000,
        "stock_quantity": 3,
        "tax_rate": 2.55,
        "tax_id": 2,
        "tax_type": "exclusive",
        "sale_unit_id": 8,
        "short_name": "box"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Smart Phone Samsung A11 Black",
        "sale_price": 12000,
        "stock_quantity": 3,
        "tax_rate": 20,
        "tax_id": 4,
        "tax_type": "inclusive",
        "sale_unit_id": 8,
        "short_name": "box"
    }
]
```

Fetched with function

```
  async function fetchProducts(name = product_q.value) {
    if (name.length < 1) {
        clearProducts();
        return;
    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/warehouse-products/${selected_warehouse.value}/${name}`);
        items.value = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
    }
}
```

Here my full Vue componenet code.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <!-- Search product input :disabled="!selected_warehouse"-->
      <div class="p-1 dropdown-search-select-box">
        <label class="my-1">Search product</label>
        <input
          
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-sm"
          placeholder="Search items..."
          v-model="product_q"
          @keyup="fetchProducts(product_q)"
        />
        <ul class="list-group dropdown-search-list" v-if="items.length > 0">
          <li
            @click="onSelectProduct(p)"
            :key="p.id"
            class="list-group-item cursor-pointer"
            v-for="p in items"
          >
            {{ p.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  
      <table
      class="table bg-white table-bordered my-3 p-1 table-responsive"
  >
      <thead>
          <tr class="bg-ass text-secondary">
              <th class="min150">Product</th>
              <th class="min100">Unit Price</th>
              <th class="">Stock</th>
              <th class="min100">Quantity</th>
              <th class="min100">Tax</th>
              <th class="min100">Subtotal</th>
              <th class="min100">action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead> 
      {{ selected_items }} 
      <tbody v-if="selected_items.length > 0">
          <tr v-for="p in selected_items">
              <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.unit_price }}</td>
              <td>
                  <input
                      type="number"
                      class="max100 form-control"
                      :value="p.product_quantity"
                      disabled
                  />
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input
                      type="number"
                      class="max100 form-control"
                      min="1"
                      v-model="p.stock_quantity"
                      @input="calculateGrandTotal()"
                  />
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{
                      (
                                p.product_quantity *
                                ((((100 - p.tax_rate) *
                                    p.sale_price) /
                                    100) *
                                    (p.tax_rate / 100))
                            ).toFixed(2)
                  }}
                  $
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{
                      p.tax_type == "exclusive"
                          ? p.product_quantity *
                            (p.sale_price * (p.tax_rate / 100) +
                                p.sale_price)
                          : p.product_quantity * p.product.sale_price
                  }}
              </td>
              <td>
                  <CrossSvgIcon
                      @click="removeSelected(p.id)"
                      color="red"
                  />...
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>{{ product_q }}
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  
  const product_q = ref('');
  const selected_warehouse = ref(1);
  const items = ref([]);
  const selected_items = ref([]);
  
  async function fetchProducts(name = product_q.value) {
    if (name.length < 1) {
        clearProducts();
        return;
    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/warehouse-products/${selected_warehouse.value}/${name}`);
        items.value = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
    }
}
  // Fetch invoice products
  const fetchInvoiceProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/products_invoice/14`);
      selected_items.value = response.data;
      console.log(selected_items)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching invoice products:', error);
    }
  };
  
  // Add a new product to the selected items
  function onSelectProduct(product) {
    const existingProduct = selected_items.value.find(
        (item) => item.id === product.id
    );
  
    if (existingProduct) {
      existingProduct.quantity += 1;
    } else {
      product.quantity = 1;
      selected_items.value.push(product);
    }
  
    clearProducts();
    product_q.value = '';
    calculateGrandTotal();
  };
  
  // Clear products in the dropdown
  const clearProducts = () => {
    items.value = [];
  };
  
  // Calculate grand total (add your logic here)
  const calculateGrandTotal = () => {
    // Add your logic to calculate the grand total
  };
  
  onMounted(() => {
    // Fetch invoice products when the component is mounted
    fetchInvoiceProducts();
    fetchProducts();
  });
  </script>
```

i am getting error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sale_price') same with all other variables in my components
```

the p.sale_price and p.name are not recognized when i am adding a new product from search input

i think the probleme is the kind of data i am getting with both function are not same !!!

and i did try many ways without success

Comment: It's not clear.  you'd greatly increase your chances of getting an answer if you actually explained your code, not just pasted it.  which variables in your code represent the arrays you posted and how are these two arrays related?   walk us through what your code is doing, or trying to do, and where exactly do you see something going wrong.  what is the flow of logic that leads to the error?  where _is_ the error? all I can gather is it's something to do with a name field but not sure exactly what or where the problem is.

Comment: thanks for your help i'll try explain my code and edit my question

Comment: Also explain your desired outcome, what is it are you looking to achieve. Your question does little to explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: i wana fetch product already attached to my invoice ID 14 for example and store them in selected_items array then loop them in my table awith possibility of adding new row by search input and add them to my invoice edit with items arraybut when i am searching a new product i can't add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just push two data structures into conformity and hope it works; you need to conform the data.

Your first step is determining what data you need from both objects and ensuring you get all the data you need from the API calls for each product.

From what I can see, you need an object with the following:

1. Id
2. Name
3. Unit Price
4. Stock Left
5. Order Quantity
6. Tax Rate
7. Tax Type

So, your selected items should always conform to this so your table can be populated correctly. For projects like this, you should use Typescript to help you. But since you are not, you need to create some conversion on the data.

Creating two functions to help force the data to a preferred structure (I did the best mapping I could; you'll need to update accordingly)

```js
  function productToProductRow(product){
    return {
      id: product.id,
      name: product.name,
      unit_price: product.sale_price,
      stock_left: product.stock_quantity,
      order_quantity: 1,
      tax_rate: product.tax_rate,
      tax_type: product.tax_type
    }
  }

  function invoiceToProductRow(invoice){
    return {
      id: invoice.product.id,
      name: invoice.product.name,
      unit_price: invoice.product.sale_price,
      stock_left: invoice.product.stock_quantity,
      order_quantity: invoice.product_quantity,
      tax_rate: invoice.product.tax_rate,
      tax_type: invoice.product.tax_type
    }

  }
```

Now, update when you assign the data. Just use the functions on each item.

```
selected_items.value = response.data
```

Should be:

```
selected_items.value = response.data.map((invoice) => invoiceToProductRow(invoice));
```

AND

```
items.value = response.data;
```

Should be:

```
items.value = response.data.map((product) => productToProductRow(product));
```

Your `<tbody>` also needs to be updated:

```js
<tbody v-if="selected_items.length > 0">
  <tr v-for="p in selected_items">
    <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.unit_price }}</td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="max100 form-control"
        :value="p.stock_left"
        disabled
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="max100 form-control"
        min="1"
        v-model="p.order_quantity"
        @input="calculateGrandTotal()"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      {{
        (
          p.order_quantity *
          ((((100 - p.tax_rate) *
            p.unit_price) /
            100) *
            (p.tax_rate / 100))
          ).toFixed(2)
      }}
      $
    </td>
    <td>
      {{
        p.tax_type == "exclusive"
          ? p.order_quantity *
            (p.unit_price * (p.tax_rate / 100) +
                p.unit_price)
          : p.order_quantity * p.unit_price
      }}
    </td>
    <td>
      <CrossSvgIcon
        @click="removeSelected(p.id)"
        color="red"
      />...
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

You should consider refactoring this component to make it more readable and also breaking it down so it's not such a large component with functionality all over the place. The table row should ideally be a child component, and the tax and sub-total computed properties should be inside that child component.

Comment: Thank you... i think if i have to make two request or flatten the array as you did.  About tour suggestions to make a child component... I should create a child vue file called datarow for example and put my table data inside and call it in my component is it sir ?

Comment: That would be ideal; then, you have to pass the required data to the component. You still need to conform the data, though, which you have a few options to handle that.